# Analyzing the code of the class files in a jar file

Tags: java, android, jar, decompiling

I'm trying to analyze the contents of android apps. I already made the code I need to analyze it if it was a human readable file format, like .java or .txt. I know how to change the decompile the apk to get the dex file and how to change the dex file into a jar file but, now, I need to be able to analyze a jar file to analyze its .class files to convert them to .java files. I was trying to use jd-core because jd-gui works so well for decompiling jar files, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I have this code snippet that unzips the jar file from  [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s/1529707#1529707):

```
java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(jarFile);
java.util.Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries();
while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
  java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enumEntries.nextElement();
  java.io.File f = new java.io.File(destDir + java.io.File.separator + file.getName());
  if (file.isDirectory()) { // if its a directory, create it
    f.mkdir();
    continue;
  }
  java.io.InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
  java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);
  while (is.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
    fos.write(is.read());
  }
  fos.close();
  is.close();
}
```

But I can't find any way to turn the class files into .java files.
Also, this unzips very very slowly. I feel like I may be going about this **completely** wrong. Any help you can give me?

Answer (score 0):

Class files are **compiled** files, which means the only way to read the code inside them would be to **decompile** them. `class` files contain byte code that is not human-readable and is not meant to be. What you could do is use a decompiler programmatically.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23218778/7954021) and [this](https://github.com/mstrobel/procyon).